# How to make rails load multiple css files

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I used to put everything into application.css before and it worked. But now I wanted to use some nice dropdown menus in my app and the css for it is huuge. So I made a new css file just for the dropdown menus in the same folder where application.css is: stylesheets

It seems now that rails does not load the newly created css file. How can I make it load every file in the folder?

Comment: What is the content of your application.css?

Comment: Before, it had all my css, now it's empty as I moved everything into a seperate file. I imagine it needs to include some code to fetch every other file in the tree? If so, what is it?

Comment: Yes, you need to include the code to load all other files. I post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put those two lines into application.css:

```
*= require_self
*= require_tree .
```

`*= require tree .` will require all css files in `app/assets/stylesheets` , `lib/assets/stylesheets` and `vendor/assets/stylesheets`

Answer (score 2):

Use the default `application.css` file, it includes all .css files in the assets directories:

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 */
```